# UpdatePanel in Master Page and FileUpload on Child Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

My updatePanel is in MasterPage and FileUpload is in Child Page.
As FileUpload requires a full PagePostBack I tried following approaches, but none of them worked, fileupload.hasfile gives false and postedfile is null. Not sure what else to do. Please go through and suggest. Is there anything that I am missing.
Using .NET Framework 4.0, Bootstrap 4

Approach 1 - Adding Postback trigger through code behind

```
  AddTriggers(btnupload.UniqueID);

    public static void AddTriggers(string ControlID)
    {
        UpdatePanel UP = Page.Master.FindControl("MainUpdPanel") as UpdatePanel;
        UpdatePanelControlTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = ControlID;
        UP.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    }
```

Approach 2 - Wrapping fileupload and it's button in a separate UpdatePanel in child Page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upld" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
       <div class="input-group form-inline">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadreq" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnupload" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnupload_Click" />
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="View" ID="lnkview" OnClick="lnkview_Click" Visible="False"></asp:LinkButton>
               </div>
               </ContentTemplate>
                 <Triggers>
                 <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnupload" />
               </Triggers>
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You could just place `FileUploadreq` and `btnupload` outside the UpdatePanel.

Comment: They are in my child page, UpdatePanel is in my MasterPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag and add the trigger in your page Page_Init function

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     AddTriggers(btnupload.UniqueID); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, adding it to Page_Init worked for me only after adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to form tag, please update your answer with this, I will mark your post as answer. Thank you soo much.